# Semi-Circular swipe scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

i've been searching for this the last couple of weeks and i can't find an answer.

[This is what i'm trying to accomplish ! Click to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgCsn.png)

I need to scroll through an infinite number of apps, on a touchscreen device.

The one in the middle needs to be bigger, and the rest smaller and smaller, to give the idea that there are more apps that are not visible and you need to touch and scroll though apps.

I'm trying to do this with Jquery, HTML5 and CSS3.

Can anybody help me, please?

I'm really stuck here..

Thank you very much!

Comment: We're not a code writing service, please at least demonstrate your attempt to date.

Comment: i'm really sorry, i'm not looking for a code writing service. I'm looking for a hint, a starting point, or an ideea that i can develop on...i just don't know where to start from. I'm sorry if i offended anyone.

Comment: The static HTML & CSS are simple to write...i will search the code i wrote and post it...but i don't know how to code the scroll/animation..

Answer (score 0):

I tried using this http://jsfiddle.net/67zMe/5/

But i had no luck making it semi-circular and based on touch screen scrolling action.

```
var radius = 300;
var angleSteps = 360 / $('#circle-list li').length;
var baseAngle = 0;

function updateListPositions()
{
    $('#circle-list li').each(function(index, element)
       {
           var angle = baseAngle + (index * angleSteps);
           var center = 150;
           var distance = 100;
           var x = distance * Math.cos(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
           var y = distance * Math.sin(angle * (Math.PI / 180));
           $(element).css({left:center+x, top:center+y});
       });
}

var stepInterval = setInterval(stepAngle, 25);

function stepAngle()
{
    baseAngle++;
    updateListPositions();
}
```

Here is the javascript. It's the closest thing i found, to what i need.

The guy who posted this, had the same problem, and didn't find the answer he needed.